# Why is total_time in CURL PHP big?

Tags: php, curl

I have php code, I send API requests to a social network. I send approximately 24 million requests per day.

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.site.com/method/messages.send');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 3);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYSTATUS, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

$curl_info = curl_getinfo($ch);

print_r($curl_info);

echo $result;
```

Requests are usually executed in 0.09-0.15 seconds. But for some unknown reasons, sometimes it happens that they are missing three seconds. `curl_getinfo` shows that connections are very fast, and processing is long. Why is this so and what does it depend on? Why is `[curl_time]` so big? **This does not always happen, but for some unknown reasons at different times**.

```
[content_type] => 
[http_code] => 0
[header_size] => 0
[request_size] => 170
[filetime] => -1
[ssl_verify_result] => 19
[redirect_count] => 0
[total_time] => 3.000928
[namelookup_time] => 0.000716
[connect_time] => 0.037246
[pretransfer_time] => 0.077432
[size_upload] => 2128
[size_download] => 0
[speed_download] => 0
[speed_upload] => 709
[download_content_length] => -1
[upload_content_length] => 2128
[starttransfer_time] => 0.077433
[redirect_time] => 0
[redirect_url] => 
[primary_ip] => XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
[certinfo] => Array
    (
    )

[primary_port] => 443
[local_ip] => XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
[local_port] => 58226
[http_version] => 0
[protocol] => 2
[ssl_verifyresult] => 0
[scheme] => HTTPS
[appconnect_time_us] => 77383
[connect_time_us] => 37246
[namelookup_time_us] => 716
[pretransfer_time_us] => 77432
[redirect_time_us] => 0
[starttransfer_time_us] => 77433
[total_time_us] => 3000928
```

As the hoster of my server said, I have no problems with the Internet. The support of the site where I send API requests also said that they have no problems.

What could be the problem? Intel Core i9 server, 24 cores and 128GB of RAM. Internet 1GBIT/sec.

Comment: We cannot somehow magically guess what might be the issue with a setup we do not know and a network we have no access to and no knowledge about. In networking there can always be delays, from simply package collisions to service rotations, endless possibilities. You will need to start debugging, monitoring the network, the specific request and most important the server side.

Comment: @arkascha, what specific settings are needed to attach it here?